# Group FaceTime link

Tags: facetime

I would like to create a link for a FaceTime video call with multiple people. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html) you can make a link to call one person like this:

```
facetime://user@example.com
```

How can I add more emails to a link like this?

Comment: A little more info: I'd like to create a shared calendar event with a URL to the video call. All users on the call will be on macOS. I've tried adding email addresses to the `facetime://` URL separated with different characters (`:`, `;`, `,`, and `+`) with no luck.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `facetime-group://` URI scheme!

It also accepts a parameter (`isVideoEnabled`) for your camera state when joining; `0` means upon joining the camera won't be activated, `1` means it will.

Example:

```
facetime-group://?remoteMembers=+12345678901;participant2@apple.com;+23456789012&isVideoEnabled=1
```

Let me know if it works for your use case!

Answer (score 2):

Apple added support for creating FaceTime links in iOS 15 and macOS Monterey 12:

1. Open FaceTime
2. Click "Create Link"

---

### [Create a link to a FaceTime call on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/create-a-facetime-link-iphfc9b58aaa/ios) (iOS 15)

> In the FaceTime app on iPhone, you can create a link to a FaceTime
> call and send the link to a friend or a group (using Mail or
> Messages), which they can use to join or start a call.
>
> 1. Tap Create Link near the top of the screen.
> 2. Choose an option for sending the link (Mail, Messages, and so on).
>
> In Calendar, you can schedule a remote video meeting by [inserting FaceTime as the location of the meeting](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/create-and-edit-events-iph3d110f84/15.0/ios/15.0#iph8f5cad4fe).
>
> Note: You can invite anyone to join you in a FaceTime call, even
> people who don’t have an Apple device. They can join you in one-on-one
> and Group FaceTime calls from their browser—no login is necessary.
> (They need the latest version of either Chrome or Edge. Sending video
> requires H.264 video encoding support.)

### [Create a link to start a FaceTime call on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/create-a-link-to-start-a-call-fctm90c6f805/mac) (macOS Monterey 12)

> When you’re signed in and FaceTime is turned on, you can create a link
> for a FaceTime call, then share that link with anyone using any device
> (Apple, Android, or Windows). As the link originator, you need to
> start the call, then allow each user to join.
>
> Note: You can invite anyone that meets [these requirements](https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/aside/glos6cfe2ae8/5.0/mac/12.0) to join you
> on a FaceTime call, even people who don’t have an Apple device.
>
> #### Create and share a FaceTime link
>
> 1. In the FaceTime app on your Mac,
>    [sign in and make sure FaceTime is turned on](https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/sign-in-to-or-out-of-facetime-on-mac-fctme7243ba3/5.0/mac/12.0).
> 2. Click Create Link.
> 3. Choose how you want to share the link. For example, choose Messages to
>    send a text message to someone that includes the link for a FaceTime
>    call.
>
> In the Calendar app, you can [add a FaceTime video call to calendar events](https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/create-a-link-to-start-a-call-fctm90c6f805/mac#:%7E:text=add%20a%20FaceTime%20video%20call%20to%20calendar%20events).
>
> To remove a FaceTime link, check the list of callers for a call made
> with a FaceTime link, click the Info button , then click Delete Link.
>
> #### Start a call from a FaceTime link
>
> If you created a link for a FaceTime
> call, you can start the call either from the app (for example, from
> the Messages conversation, click Join) or from FaceTime. If you
> created the link in the last day or so, you see it in the list of
> recent calls in the Upcoming section; otherwise, you see it in the
> date-based section—for example, below Last Week.
>
> 1. In the FaceTime app on your Mac, move the pointer over the call
>    window and find the call made with a FaceTime link, then click the
>    Video button.
> 2. Click Join.
>
> #### Let a caller join the FaceTime call
>
> The originator of the FaceTime
> link can let you in to the call immediately. Other callers (who are
> using Apple devices, who have been approved, and who have joined the
> call for at least 30 seconds) can also approve (or decline) requests
> to join the call.
>
> You know that a new caller is waiting when a badge appears on the
> Sidebar button.
>
> 1. In the FaceTime app on your Mac on a FaceTime call, click the Sidebar
>    button when you see the badge.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Allow the caller in the call: Click the Approve Join Request button .
>    - Don’t allow the caller in the call: Click the Decline Join Request
>      button .
>
> To turn off the audio alert when a new person joins the call, click
> the Sidebar button, then select Silence Join Requests.

Source: support.apple.com